# How to use 'catdoc' to display dock file encoded in utf-8

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

I have a a lot of docx files and I want to read them on terminal. And I found catdoc 
http://www.wagner.pp.ru/~vitus/software/catdoc/

When I use it, the output are just unreadable chars. My docx files are encoded in utf-8. I tried "catdoc -u my_file.docx" but does not work.

Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

docx are zipped XML files.

To extract and strip the XML try something based on

```
unzip -p "*.docx" word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g'
```

from [command line fu](http://g33kinfo.com/info/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/comfu1.txt)

Answer (score 1):

It is my naïve understanding that `catdoc` can generally only be used on `DOC` files. `DOCX` files are something like a zipped container with a bunch of information in them; among which you can find the original document in some sort of XML format.

Having said that, I have had pleasant success extracting the contents of `DOCX` files, or even `DOTX` files for that matter, using either [doc2txt](http://docx2txt.sourceforge.net/#code) tool or the [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/#download) tool, the latter of which needs the OpenOffice or LibreOffice suite installed.

Here are some example workflows, which I have used successfully in the past:

```bsh
# This one, contrary to the unoconv case, does not fire up an instance
# of either LibreOffice or OpenOffice.
docx2txt.pl < ./pesky-word-doc.docx > ./pesky-word-doc.txt

# This one, however, does fire up a rather heavy 'headless' OpenOffice
# or LibreOffice instance process per conversion. You can get around this
# using the next approach below.
unoconv -f txt -o ./pesky-word-doc.txt ./pesky-word-doc.docx

# If you need to convert a couple of dozens such documents, you might want
# to run it via a service port (you get the idea):
unoconv --listener --port=2002 &
unoconv -f txt -o outdir *.docx
unoconv -f pdf -o outdir *.docx && open ./outdir/*.pdf # Convenient, if you run MacOSX
kill -15 %-

# Kind of introducing catdoc: The sed was needed for German documents where
# somehow I couldn't find the proper encoding settings.
unoconv -f doc -o ./pesky-word-doc.doc ./pesky-word-doc.docx && \
          catdoc -u ./pesky-word-doc.doc | sed 's/ь/ü/g;s/д/ä/g;s/ц/ö/g'
```

There are other options, like using some of the available java parsers to be found [here](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/TextUtils.java) and [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/docxtoany/?source=navbar). The output quality differs and depending on your intended usage requires you to go for either one of the approaches.