# Version control Word .docx files with docx2txt with Git on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, git, terminal, ms-word, installation

On `Git` web site there is a detailed instruction for version controling Microsoft Word `.doc` files with `catdoc`.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

However, I realized that this doesn't work for `.docx` files. It seems that you need either `docx2txt` or `unoconv` instead of `catdoc` ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557573/how-to-use-catdoc-to-display-dock-file-encoded-in-utf-8)). I decided to go with `docx2txt` for no reason, but I was stuck at the installation of `docx2txt` into Mac OS X.

[This](https://gist.github.com/nachocab/6429893) sort of illustrates the steps. In my understanding, all you need is `docx2txt.pl` at somewhere sensible. I thought `/usr/local/bin/` would do. I copied it there. Then, according to [the instruction](https://gist.github.com/nachocab/6429893), I tried the following:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin/
$ echo '#!/bin/bash
docx2txt.pl "$1" -' > docx2txt
```

When I try this:

```
$ docx2txt
```

I got

```
Can't read docx file <>!
```

so, `docx2txt` seems to be in the path.

Then I edited `.gitattributes` in the repository folder (ASCII, LF) to add the following line:

```
*.docx diff=wordx
```

Then, I also edited .git/config file in the repository as follows:

```
[diff "wordx"]
    binary = true
    textconv = docx2txt
```

Because the repository is already in use, I didn't do `git init`. I edited a .docx Word file in the repository and then typed `git diff` in the Terminal. But result was not successful.

```
Binary files a/foo/foo.docx and b/foo/foo.docx differ
```

Could anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you chmod +x on the docx2txt?

Comment: I didn't, but thanks to your post, I somehow realized I was using a wrong directory `/usr/bin/` instead of `/usr/local/bin/`. This solved the problem in installation, but I couldn't go further. I'll update my question.

Comment: The only thing I can see, that I've done different than above is, `sudo make` to install docx2txt. I'm now diffing .dotx files flawlessly on OSX, thanks! (the `binary = true` option is not needed, btw, so the .git/config can be set from the commandline like this: `git config diff.wordx.textconv docx2txt`, where docx2txt is given above and placed in $PATH if it isn't and if it can't see docx2txt.pl, the script woun't run and you will fall back to the usual "binary files a/blah b/blah differs")

Comment: I did this: https://gist.github.com/klang/11172484

Comment: Cheers. Sounds promising. I'll give it a try later.

Comment: Thanks, klang. I tried your methods and it worked! I can diff word .docx files on Terminal.app window now. I found two minor typos in your Gist and left comments there as kouichi-c-nakamura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to klang, I made it. Now I can diff .docx files in Terminal.app in Mac OS X (10.9). But this one doesn't seamlessly work with SourceTree GUI. Below is basically the same as klang's but with minor corrections.

Download and install the **docx2txt** converter from http://docx2txt.sourceforge.net/

```
wget -O doc2txt.tar.gz http://docx2txt.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/docx2txt/?view=tar
tar zxf doc2txt.tar.gz
cd docx2txt/docx2txt/
sudo make
```

Then make a small wrapper script to make docx2txt output to STDOUT

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
docx2txt.pl "$1" -' > /usr/local/bin/docx2txt
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docx2txt
```

**Git attributes for (Word) .docx diffing** in your repository

```
echo "*.docx diff=wordx" >> .gitattributes
git config diff.wordx.textconv docx2txt
```

Use `.git/info/attributes` if the setting should not be committed with the project.

**Git attributes for (Word) .doc diffing**

```
echo "*.doc diff=word" >> .gitattributes
git config diff.word.textconv strings
```